# Run python script with flask from web without clicking any button

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

In my application, I need to open web cam inside webpage and also I need to process web cam frame and return result to webpage again. To do that I am not using buttons. I found that how to use webcam in webpage in here

[web cam in a webpage using flask and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54786145/web-cam-in-a-webpage-using-flask-and-python)

However I cannot pass the result to the webpage. How can I pass the result to the same webpage ? Without clicking any button. In my case how can I call, index2() function from web ?

## Python

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response, jsonify
from camera import VideoCamera
import cv2

app = Flask(__name__)

video_stream = VideoCamera()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

def gen(camera):
    while True:
        frame = camera.get_frame()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')

@app.route('/video_feed')
   def video_feed():
        return Response(gen(video_stream),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')


@app.route('/print2')
def index2():
    print2 = video_stream.get_print()
    print("zzzz",print2)
    return render_template('gui.html', printTo=print2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', debug=True,port="5000")
```

## Python camera.py

```
class VideoCamera(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    def __del__(self):
        self.video.release()        

    def get_frame(self):
        ret, frame = self.video.read()

        # DO WHAT YOU WANT WITH TENSORFLOW / KERAS AND OPENCV

        ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)

        return jpeg.tobytes()
```

## HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Video Stream</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <img src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}" />
  </body>
</html>
```

In **camera.py** script I can process frame and I can print the results to log however I need to pass these results to the webpage.

I did many thing and none of them worked for me !

Please help me.

Thank you.

## EDIT

As the comments states, as far as I understand I can do it with AJAX and I added this script but now script gives error

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
     function plot() {


    $.ajax({
        url: '/print2',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('get info');

            $('#description').html(data['description']);
        }
    });


}

   plot()
</script>
```

It says

(index):30 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at plot ((index):30)
    at (index):38

Where is the problem ?

Comment: you don't have `index2()` in code in question.

Comment: I have. It is writeen above camera.py. Look carefully please.

Comment: with print route header

Comment: now I see I was looking only on name in route.

Comment: you will have to use JavaScript which will get data (without all HTML) from flask and change it in HTML which is already in browser .

Comment: Is there a way, call this route without clicking any button ?

Comment: yes, use JavaScript to call it. But it has to return only this part of HTML which you want to change in page and JavaScript will have to replace it. It is called AJAX.

Comment: Thank you I will google it. I have one more question, with AJAX can I display the both camera and the result of the index2 at same page?

Comment: AJAX can get part of HTML from index2 and replace this part on page which already display camera. Or it can get full HTML which should use `<img src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}" />` to display image, and replace all HTML in browser.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" >
     function plot() {


    $.ajax({
        url: '/print2',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('get info');

            $('#description').html(data['description']);
        }
    });


} Is it correct ? I try this but it gaves error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199634/discussion-between-ozer-and-furas).

Answer (score 0):

Have you included a reference to jQuery?

```
(index):30 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at plot ((index):30) at (index):38
```